# NSIS Read/Write in a file and blowfish issue

Tags: nsis

Here is my issue. I need to create a file with several lines and encrypt the info using blowfish. That I have done. Then in another program I need to read the file and decrypt it. It works if I only create one line. But as soon as I create more lines i run into issues, it does not matter if I use FileRead or use an ini format and use ReadINIStr.

It seems the issue must be that it reads and returns and new line as part of the field so when it goes to decrypt it, it screws up. how can I read just the complete line without the returns and new line as part of the field?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I was using a 64 key for blowfish and it had special char's and one was a ' so it was reading it all weird. changed it to text and numbers only and now it works. Hope this helps someone in the future.